# Why won't my indexed list variable work properly?

Tags: python

I have a `randint` variable that can go from 1 to the amount of words in a string. The string is currently 6 words long, thus the number can be between 1 and 6.

If the number is greater than 4, I want it to be 4. I tried using the following snippet of code:

```
if wwlIndexer > 4:
    wwlIndexer = 4

ordinal = WhatWordList[wwlIndexer]
```

But that gives back the following error message:

```
 list index out of range -
   File "C:\Users\redacted\Coding bullshit\Experimentation.py", line 16, in <module>
     ordinal = WhatWordList[wwlIndexer]
```

For context, the whole code I'm trying to make work looks like this:

```
from random import randint

print('--------------------')

myString = 'I am a cool little bastard'
WhatWordList = ['st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th']
wwlIndexer = 0

for n in range(5):
    myStringLength = len(myString.split(' '))
    randomNumber = randint(1, myStringLength)
    wwlIndexer = randomNumber 
    if wwlIndexer > 4:
        wwlIndexer = 4

    ordinal = WhatWordList[wwlIndexer]

    print('----')
    print('The length of the string is:', myStringLength, 'words')
    print('The random number is', randomNumber)

    print('The ' + str(randomNumber) + str(ordinal) + ' is ' + str(myString.split(' ')[randomNumber - 
1]))
    print('----')
    print()
    print()
```

Comment: `wwlIndexer = min(4, wwlIndexer)`.

Comment: Well, my previous comment answers the titel of your question, but it looks like your actual question is different. Make sure your question title is relevant.

Comment: The maximum index your `WhatWordList` can take is `3`, you are giving it `4`. Maybe your cap value should be `3` instead of `4`

Comment: Why not just `randomNumber = randint(1, 4)`? But note that list indexes start from zero so you actually want `randomNumber = randint(0, 3)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo or, `randrange(0, 4)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga even better: `randrange(len(WhatWordList))` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, in Python, according to PEP-8 guidelines, you want to declare variables like `one_variable`, **not** like `oneVariable`. And then, in `WhatWordList` are four elements. But as Python indexes the first element of a list as 0, the second one as 1 etc., the list‘s last element has an index of 3. Thus your code won‘t work if `wwlIndexer >= 4`. You may try the using the following line of code:

```
ordinal = what_word_list[wwl_indexer-1]
```

Comment: But is there anything enherantly wrong with my way of making variables? I just prefer how it looks, and so far it does not seem to be a "wrong" way of doing it

Comment: @Divide05 If you want to code in Python, it is better to follow international, long-time conventions that all people writing Python use...

Comment: yes, I agree with Tomerikoo, because if other people also read your code, it‘s better to have the same structure as them. Check out this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Python are zero-indexed. The index of the first element in a list is 0.

In a list of 4 elements, the last element index is 3, not 4.

Comment: I may be a bit stupid, but I did this,
 if wwlIndexer > 3:
        wwlIndexer = 3


But now I'm running into this issue:
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
  File "C:\Users\Emma Lindberg\Coding bullshit\Experimentation.py", line 16, in <module>
    ordinal = WhatWordList[wwlIndexer] - 1

Answer (score 0):

You are seeking for an answer to the wrong problem. You did it right with `wwlIndexer` but the problem is with accessing the array.

In most programming languages arrays begin counting from 0, not from 1.

The last element of `WhatWordList = ['st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th']` is `WhatWordList[3]`, not `WhatWordList[4]`